# Updating row using sqlalchemy and Scrapy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I have some data in a sqllite table which I am interacting with use sqlalchemy. I'm trying to take a table row, with a blank field , scrape the info for the blank field and then update the field in the row. I've got:

```
engine = create_engine(db_path)
Base = declarative_base()
# metadata = Base.metadata
# Look up the existing tables from database
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)


def object_as_dict(obj):
    return {c.key: getattr(obj, c.key)
            for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs}


class Get_blank_field_spider(Spider):


    def start_requests(self):

        source_table= self.source
        # NOTE THAT type CREATES A CLASS OF name = source_table
        table = type(source_table, (Base,), {"__tablename__": source_table,
                                             "__mapper_args__": {
                                                 "primary_key": [Base.metadata.tables[source_table].c.id]}})

        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()

        i = 0
        s = session.query(table)
        for row in s.limit(300):

            i += 1
            print object_as_dict(row)
            d = object_as_dict(row)



            yield Request(url=myurl, headers= headers, callback=self.parse_blank_field_lookup,meta={'d':d, 'cookiejar': i, 'session':s },dont_filter = True)


    def parse_blank_field_lookup(self, response):

        d = response.meta['d']
        i = response.meta['cookiejar']
        s = response.meta['session']

        try:
            blank_field = response.xpath('//PATH GOES HERE').extract_first()
            d['blank_field']= blank_field
            print d
        except:
            d['blank_field']= 'not found'


        s.filter_by(id=d['id']).update(d)
        # s.commit()
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass through the session and update the entire row by passing in a dictionary (d) after updating d with the scraped data by looking up the correct row and using the update function. This is not updating the row in the table itself, although no error is generated. How can I get this working?

Comment: you've got an `except` eating errors... my guess is that the session is not passing through. but you are in a class - you should set a class attribute instead.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: If you put `raise` in your `except` line, it will throw the error instead of eating it. But more usefully, the meta may be mangling the session... instead you can just do `self.session = session` and then in the other function reference `self.session`...

Comment: Sorry, does not work . no error is  generated but the table row is not updated